# Question on Separation of Variables to Prove A General Example of Non-uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the full problem I am working on. 
[image: This is the full problem]

What I really need help with is finding the solution x(t) through separation of variables for part (a). I know that since the derivative is nonnegative and x(0)=0, x(t) should be nonnegative.

When I did separation of variables on my own I got [image]

However, I keep finding solutions online which have the solution stated as [image]

What am I doing wrong and where does the t_0 come in? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For part $b,$ notice that with $F(x,t)=|x|^{p/q},\ F_x$ is continuous on a rectangle $[-\delta,\delta]\times [-t_0,t_0]$ so the result follows by the exsitence-uniqueness theorem.

For part $a,$ set $r:=p/q$ and notice that $x=0$ is a solution. Then, $\frac{dx}{x^{r}}=dt\Rightarrow \int_0^x\frac{dz}{z^r}=t+c_1,$ where the LHS is a convergent improper integral because $0<r<1$ and $c_1\in \mathbb R$ is arbitrary. It follows that $x(t)=c(t-c_1)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}$ for  arbitrary $c\in \mathbb R$ and now, taking $c_1=0,$ that

$$x_c(t)=\begin{cases}
0&t<0,\\
ct^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}&t\geq 0 
\end{cases}$$

is an infinte family of solutions.